# Интерфейс, не содержащий ни одного члена

Tags: java, интерфейс

Возможен ли `интерфейс`, не содержащий ни одного члена, и если да, какой практический смысл от такого интерфейса?

Comment: может. для группировки некоторых классов, например.

Comment: Все зависит от фантазии

Comment: Мне кажется в течении месяца такой же вопрос уже задавали.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Да, возможен. Такие интерфейсы называют маркерными. Они нужны для индикации чего-либо JVM, компилятору или какой-либо библиотеке. Пустые они потому, что позволяют добавить некоторый признак/маркер/индикацию к типам, *не меняя* контракты этих типов.

В Джаве такими интерфейсами являются, например, `Serializable` и `Cloneable`. Существование `Serializable` позволяет сделать проверку "можно ли сериализовать этот объект" более типизированным образом, сведя ее к проверке "имплементирует ли этот объект интерфейс `Serializable`".

Заменой маркерным интерфейсам также могут служить аннотации (например, `@ThreadSafe`).

[Интерфейс-маркер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) на Википедии.

Answer (score 8):

Да, это возможно.

Существует шаблон, который называется **интерфейс-маркер**. Классы реализуют интерфейс не содержащий, ни одного метода. Это требуется для того, чтобы отметить определенные классы, с которыми в дальнейшим возможны, какие-то определенные действия.

Чтобы было понятнее, приведу пример. В стандартной библиотеке существует интерфейс `java.lang.Cloneable`. Он показывает, что *переопределеный* метод в классе `java.lang.Object.clone()` будет возвращать копию объекта данного класса.